# WebSocket, even after firing onopen event, still in CONNECTING state

Tags: javascript, typescript, websocket

WebSocket send method throws exception even on trying after onconnect.
Not always, but many times I see the logged exceptions in console.

This is the typescript code:-

```
  open() {
    if ('WebSocket' in window) {
      this.ws = new WebSocket(ApiUrls.Socket(''));
      this.ws.onopen = () => {
        const authentication = {
          msgType : 'Authenticate',
          data : {
            token : localStorage.getItem('authToken')
          }
        }
        this.ws.send(JSON.stringify(authentication));
      };

      this.ws.onmessage = (evt) => {
        // console.log(evt);
        this.parseMessage(evt.data);
      };

      this.ws.onclose = () => {
        this.connected = false;
        // console.log('retrying connection with server');
        if (localStorage.getItem('authToken')) {
          this.reconnectTimeout = setTimeout(this.open.bind(this), 1000);
        }
      };
    } else {
      alert('WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!');
    }
  }
```

Exception in console:-

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at WebSocket.ws.onopen [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYopen] (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:5586:26)
    at WebSocket.wrapFn (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3711:39)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2970:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:87677:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2969:36)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2737:47)
    at ZoneTask.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3044:34)
    at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:4085:14)
    at WebSocket.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:4111:17)
```

It's too verbose, but concerned message is, `ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
        at WebSocket.ws.onopen [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYopen]`.

Comment: @Dummy Because what else I can do, I am sending a message just after the connection opens, why it's still in connecting state I am not able to figure out

Answer (score 6):

This breaks when the open method is called twice. In that case the ws property is overwritten with a new Websocket that is still in connecting state. The wrong WebSocket is then used in the onopen handler (which is async).

```
const local_websocket = new WebSocket(ApiUrls.Socket(''));
this.ws = local_websocket;
this.ws.onopen = () => {
    const authentication = {
        msgType : 'Authenticate',
        data : {
            token : localStorage.getItem('authToken')
        }
    }
    local_websocket.send(JSON.stringify(authentication));
};
```

Comment: So basically I have to find out if I am opening socket twice by any mistake

Comment: Or you could at least make sure that the send is called on a locally scoped variable. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: That resolved my query.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this seems to help:

```
this.ws.onopen = (e) => {
  // Not sure if the following line is necessary but doesn't hurt
  if (e.target.readyState !== WebSocket.OPEN) return;
  const authentication = {
    msgType : 'Authenticate',
    data : {
      token : localStorage.getItem('authToken')
    }
  }

  // Here's the key: use the websocket instance that triggered the onopen event
  e.target.send(JSON.stringify(authentication));
}
```

The difference is that you use the websocket instance that triggered the onopen event instead of the one that is living in your `this.ws` variable, since `this.ws` could have changed in the meantime.